# How to scrape multiple hierarchy from a website's menu bar?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape all the information present inside a website's menu/navigation bar **while maintaining it's hierarchy.**
Example:
https://www.trumpf.com/en_IN/
[image: The image shows the levels of hierarchy in the contents of a the menu of a site]

I have used beautiful soup to get the contents of the navigation bar however, I'm getting repeated information and hierarchical information is also lost.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
 
url = 'https://www.trumpf.com/en_IN/'
html_text = requests.get(url).text
soup = bs(html_text, 'html.parser')
d = {}

for e in soup.select('nav > ul > li'):
    s = list(e.stripped_strings)
    d.update({s[0]: s[1:]})

print(d)
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

Whereas I would like the output to have nested dictionaries and lists to preserve the hierarchy, for example;

```json
{'Products':{'Machine & Systems': ['2D laser cutting machines', '3D laser cutting machines', 'Laser welding systems and the arc welding cell', 'Laser tube cutting machines', 'Marking systems', 'Additive production systems', 'Punching machines', 'Punch laser machines', 'Bending machines', 'Storage systems', 'Automation'], 'Lasers': [...]},'Solutions':{}...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.trumpf.com/en_IN/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")


def get_tree(soup, lvl=1):
    # are we at last level?
    if not soup.select_one(f".ux-iws-nav__lvl{lvl+1}-item"):
        return [
            a.get_text(strip=True)
            for a in soup.select(f".ux-iws-nav__lvl{lvl}-item a")[1:]
        ]

    out = {}
    for li in soup.select(f".ux-iws-nav__lvl{lvl}-item"):
        t = li.a.text
        if t.startswith("Overview"):
            continue
        out[t] = get_tree(li, lvl + 1)
    return out


print(get_tree(soup.select_one("nav")))
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "Products": {
        "Machines & systems": [
            "2D laser cutting machines",
            "3D laser cutting machines",
            "Laser welding systems and the arc welding cell",
            "Laser tube cutting machines",
            "Marking systems",
            "Additive production systems",
            "Punching machines",
            "Punch laser machines",
            "Bending machines",
            "Storage systems",
            "Automation",
        ],
        "Lasers": [
            "Disk lasers",
            "Fiber laser",
            "Diode lasers",
            "Short and ultrashort pulse laser",
            "Marking lasers",
            "Pulsed lasers",
            "CO2 lasers",
            "EUV Drive Laser",
            "Sensor system",
            "Processing optics",
            "Technology packages",
            "Scientific lasers",
        ],
        "VCSEL solutions & photodiodes": [
            "Single & multimode VCSEL",
            "Datacom VCSELs & photodiodes",
            "Integrated VCSEL solutions",
            "VCSEL heating systems",
        ],
        "Real-time localization (RTLS)": [],
        "Power electronics": [
            "Plasma Excitation",
            "Induction generators",
            "Inverters",
            "TRUMPF Hüttinger Whitepaper",
        ],
        "Power tools": [
            "Battery machines",
            "Slitting shears",
            "Shear cutting",
            "Nibbler",
            "Profile nibbler",
            "Panel cutter",
            "Fiber Composite Nibbler",
            "Seam locker",
            "Power fastener",
            "Deburrers",
            "Beveler",
            "Slat cleaner",
        ],
        "Software": [],
        "Services": [],
    },
    "Solutions": {
        "Smart Factory": [
            "Smart Factory",
            "Starting out",
            "Step-by-step expansion",
            "Fully networked",
            "Smart Factory Consulting",
            "Our Smart Factories",
            "Lot size of 1",
            "Transparency with real-time locating systems",
            "Smart Material Flow",
        ],
        "Applications": [
            "Laser welding",
            "Arc welding",
            "Laser cutting",
            "EUV lithography",
            "Additive manufacturing",
            "Surface processing with the laser",
            "Microprocessing",
            "Laser marking",
            "Plasma technology",
            "Induction heating",
            "Cutting",
            "Joining",
            "Edge forming",
            "Punching and nibbling",
            "Bending",
            "Optical sensing",
        ],
        "Industries": [
            "Automotive",
            "Construction industry",
            "Sheet metal processing",
            "Dental",
            "Data communication",
            "Displays",
            "Electronics",
            "Air conditioning and energy technology",
            "Aviation and aerospace",
            "Machine and systems engineering",
            "Medical technology",
            "Commercial vehicles and transport",
            "Photovoltaics",
            "Watch and jewelry industry",
            "Tool and mold making",
            "Science",
        ],
        "Success stories": [],
        "Advantages of TRUMPF machines": [
            "Advantages of 2D laser cutting machines",
            "Advantages of bending machines",
            "Advantages of punching machines",
            "Advantages of punch laser machines",
            "Advantages of laser tube cutting machines",
            "Advantages of the TRUMPF VCSEL",
            "Advantages of additive production systems",
        ],
    },
    "Company": {
        "TRUMPF Group": [
            "Management Board",
            "Company profile",
            "Supervisory Board",
            "Locations",
            "Events and dates for your calendar",
            "Annual report",
            "Suppliers",
            "SYNCHRO",
            "Quality",
            "Company Principles",
            "Milestones in the history of TRUMPF",
            "Affiliated companies and other brands",
            "TRUMPF Venture",
            "Financial Services",
        ],
        "Responsibility": [
            "Culture",
            "Employees",
            "Education",
            "Society",
            "Products and supply chain",
            "Environment",
        ],
    },
    "Newsroom": [],
    "Careers": {
        "Vacancies": [],
        "TRUMPF as an employer": [
            "TRUMPF as an employer",
            "Benefits and opportunities",
            "Diversity",
            "Development opportunities",
            "International work",
        ],
        "Experienced professionals": [],
        "Graduates": [],
        "College students": [],
        "High school students": [],
        "How to apply": [],
        "People at TRUMPF": [],
    },
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However, the above solution is particularly for the mentioned website and not a generalized approach. Is it possible to have a generalized code that can work for most of the websites?

Comment: @Rovsh No, every website is different - with different class names (sometimes there isn't any), different HTML and link structure. There always be exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a generic solution to find menu bars and menu dropdown items, based on the presence of `ul` and `li` tags in at least one `nav` container on the page. The simplest approach is to search for `ul` elements in `nav` containers, and when a `ul` is found, look in the element's siblings for descriptive text that forms the basis of a `key` for the `ul`'s values:

```
import bs4, requests
def to_dict(r):
   if all(isinstance(i, dict) for i in r):
      return {a:b for i in r for a, b in i.items()}
   if all(isinstance(i, list) for i in r):
      return [i for b in r for i in b]
   return r

def get_menu(page_name):
   if page_name.name == 'li':
      #collect all li values, create a dictionary if li has a ul child
      li_text = []
      for i in page_name.contents:
         if isinstance(i, bs4.element.NavigableString) or i.select_one('ul') is None:
           if (t:=i.get_text(strip=True)): #default li text
              li_text.append(t)
         else: #li contains a ul, build a dict with li's text as key
            if li_text:
               li_text.append({li_text.pop():to_dict([*get_menu(i)])})
            else:
               yield to_dict([*get_menu(i)])
      yield from li_text
      return
   all_text = []
   for i in page_name.contents:
      if getattr(i, 'name', None) == 'ul':
         r = [*get_menu(i)] #get ul's li values
         e, flag = i, False
         while (e:=e.previous_sibling) is not None: #check if ul has descriptive text
           if (isinstance(e, bs4.element.NavigableString) or e.select_one('ul') is None) and e.get_text(strip=True):
              yield {e.get_text(strip=True):to_dict(r)} #yield back dictionary if text exists
              flag = True
              break
         if not flag: yield to_dict(r)
      elif not isinstance(i, bs4.element.NavigableString):
         yield from get_menu(i) #recursively traverse element

def menu_items(link):
   page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).text, 'html.parser')
   for nav in page.select('nav'): #find all `nav` elements from which to anchor search
      yield to_dict([*get_menu(nav)])
```

---

```
import json
for i in menu_items('https://www.crowncastle.com/'):
   print(json.dumps(i, indent=4))

for i in menu_items('https://ricardo.com/'):
   print(json.dumps(i, indent=4))

for i in menu_items('https://bv.com/'):
   print(json.dumps(i, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
    "Municipalities",
    "Property Owners",
    "Investors",
    "CCIsites",
    "Careers"
]
[
    "About us",
    {
        "Infrastructure Solutions": {
            "Wireless solutions": [
                "Towers",
                "Small cells"
            ],
            "Fiber solutions": [
                "Dark Fiber",
                "Ethernet",
                "Wavelength",
                "Managed SD-WAN",
                "Internet Access",
                "Private Networks",
                "Colocation"
            ],
            "Added fiber solutions": [
                "Cloud Connect",
                "Optical Encryption",
                "DDoS Defense",
                "Managed Security",
                "Bandwidth on Demand",
                "Fixed Wireless",
                "Ultra-Low Latency",
                "Video Transport"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "Industry expertise": {
            "Accelerating network connections": [
                "Financial Services",
                "Professional Services",
                "Technology Companies",
                "Gaming",
                "Media & Entertainment"
            ],
            "Transforming Public Infrastructure": [
                "Federal Government",
                "State and Local Government",
                "Education",
                "Healthcare",
                "Utilities",
                "Public Safety"
            ],
            "Scaling Networks Nationwide": [
                "Wireless Carriers",
                "Broadcast",
                "WISPs and Other Telecoms",
                "Cable",
                "Wholesale"
            ],
            "Enhancing Visitor Experiences": [
                "Commercial Real Estate",
                "Venues",
                "Hospitality",
                "Retail"
            ],
            "Building Industrial Networks": [
                "Manufacturing",
                "Oil and Gas",
                "Internet of Things",
                "Transportation"
            ]
        }
    },
    "YOUR COMMUNITY",
    "News",
    "Municipalities",
    "Property Owners",
    "Investors",
    "CCIsites",
    "Careers"
]
[
    "Network Operations Center",
    "Careers",
    "Channel Partners",
    "Municipalities",
    "Investors",
    "Fiber Referral Rewards",
    "Connected by Good",
    "ESG Overview",
    "Suppliers",
    "Media Center",
    "Resources",
    "Our History",
    "Contact Us"
]
```

---

```
[
    "About us",
    "Market sectors",
    "Services",
    "Investors",
    "News and media"
]
[
    "Follow Ricardo Plc",
    "Contact us",
    "Careers",
    "eStore"
]
{
    "About us": [
        "What we do",
        "Our people",
        "Our mission and vision",
        "Our values",
        "Our history",
        "Careers with Ricardo",
        "Our locations",
        "Innovation"
    ],
    "Market sectors": [
        "Energy & environment",
        "Automotive",
        "Commercial Vehicles",
        "Defence",
        "Defense (USA)",
        "Motorsport",
        "Motorcycle",
        "Off-highway vehicles",
        "Rail",
        "Marine",
        "Aerospace"
    ],
    "Services": [
        "Assurance and certification",
        "Centre of knowledge",
        "Energy consulting",
        "Engines",
        "Environmental consulting",
        "Hybrid and electric vehicles",
        "Software",
        "Strategic consulting",
        "Testing",
        "Transmissions and drivelines",
        "Vehicle engineering",
        "Manufacturing"
    ],
    "Investors": [
        "Announcements & tools",
        "Financial reporting",
        "Shareholder centre",
        "Governance",
        "AGM",
        "Financial calendar"
    ],
    "News and media": [
        "Resources",
        "News and Press",
        "Ricardo Quarterly magazine",
        "Webinars"
    ]
}
```

---

```
[
    [
        "Home",
        "Industries",
        "CommercialConnected Communities/Smart CitiesData CentersFood & BeverageGovernmentsIndustrial & ManufacturingManagement ConsultingMiningGas, Fuels & ChemicalsPower UtilitiesTelecommunicationsTransportationWater",
        "Services",
        "Asset ManagementConstructionConsultingData AnalyticsEngineeringEnvironmentalMaster PlanningProcurementProgram & Risk ManagementProject Development",
        "Solutions",
        "COVID-19DecarbonizationDistributed InfrastructureHydrogenInfrastructure LifecycleSmart CitiesSustainability",
        {
            "Company": [
                "About Us",
                "COVID-19 Update",
                "History",
                "Investing in Innovation",
                "Leadership",
                "Board of DirectorsLeadership Team",
                "Mission, Vision, Values",
                "Awards & Rankings"
            ]
        },
        "Culture",
        "Diversity, Equity & InclusionQualitySafety & HealthCorporate SustainabilityWorkforce of the Future",
        "Careers",
        "BenefitsCollege StudentsCultureMilitary/VeteransBV Knowledge Network",
        "Insights",
        "Insights and ResourcesStrategic Directions ReportsNews",
        "Subscribe",
        "Contact Us",
        {
            "Locations": [
                "Americas",
                "Chile",
                "Asia Pacific",
                "AustraliaChinaIndiaIndonesiaPhilippinesSingaporeSingaporeThailand",
                "Europe, Middle East and Africa",
                "United Kingdom"
            ]
        }
    ],
    [
        "Contact us",
        "Subscribe",
        {
            "Americas": [
                "Canada",
                "Chile",
                "Puerto Rico",
                "United States"
            ],
            "Asia Pacific": [
                "Australia",
                "China",
                "India",
                "Indonesia",
                "New Zealand",
                "Philippines",
                "Singapore",
                "Thailand",
                "Vietnam"
            ],
            "Europe, Middle East and Africa": [
                "Armenia",
                "Azerbaijan",
                "Germany",
                "Ireland",
                "Kazakhstan",
                "Qatar",
                "South Africa",
                "Ukraine",
                "United Kingdom"
            ]
        }
    ],
    [
        "Industries",
        "Services & Solutions",
        "Company",
        "Careers"
    ],
    {
        "Industries": [
            "Commercial",
            "Connected Communities",
            "Data Centers",
            "Food & Beverage",
            "Gas, Fuels & Chemicals",
            "Governments",
            "Industrial & Manufacturing",
            "Management Consulting",
            "Mining",
            "Power Utilities",
            "Telecommunications",
            "Transportation",
            "Water"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Services": [
            "Asset Management",
            "Construction",
            "Consulting",
            "Data Analytics",
            "Engineering",
            "Environmental",
            "Master Planning",
            "Procurement",
            "Program Management",
            "Project Development"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Solutions": [
            "BV Health Solutions",
            "Decarbonization",
            "Distributed Infrastructure",
            "Grid Modernization",
            "Hydrogen",
            "Infrastructure Lifecycle",
            "Smart Cities",
            "Sustainability"
        ]
    },
    [
        "About Us",
        "COVID-19 Update",
        "History",
        "Investing in Innovation",
        "Leadership",
        "Mission, Vision, Values",
        "Awards & Rankings"
    ],
    {
        "Culture": [
            "Corporate Sustainability",
            "Diversity, Equity & Inclusion",
            "Employee Ownership",
            "Quality",
            "Safety & Health",
            "Workforce of the Future"
        ]
    },
    [
        "Careers",
        "Benefits",
        "Culture",
        "Military/Veterans",
        "College Students",
        "BV Knowledge Network"
    ],
    {
        "Insights": [
            "Insights and Resources",
            "Strategic Directions Reports",
            "News"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Connect": [
            "Contact Us",
            "Subscribe"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Getting a syntax error for 
"if (t:=i.get_text(strip=True)):" and "while (e:=e.previous_sibling)".
and when I change ":=" to "==", I'm getting "name 't' is not defined" error.

Comment: @Rovsh `:=` is an [assignment expression](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/), available in Python >= 3.8

Comment: [link]https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1x6DH5ytb1mo6jDuEHDfRIGN3YhjPTyEw?usp=sharing[link]
can you check what's wrong with the code, pls?

Comment: @Rovsh change `(t==i.get_text(strip=True))` to `(t:=i.get_text(strip=True))` and ensure that you are running your notebook on a version of Python >= 3.8

Comment: google colab has >=3.8 only and it is still not working in it after the above changes - **"NameError: name 't' is not defined"**

Comment: @Rovsh You still need to change `(t==i.get_text(strip=True))` to `(t:=i.get_text(strip=True))` and `(e==e.previous_sibling)` to `(e:=e.previous_sibling)`

Comment: I updated Google Colab's kernel to Python version 3.8.1 but still i'm getting a syntax error. Can you please review the code, I think there is some missing piece with the code. Thanks